# Getting org.jpos.core.ConfigurationException: Port value not set Error

Tags: java, xml, jpos

Below is the log in the console generated while running from springboot..

```xml
<log realm="xml-server-8000" at="2022-10-06T11:53:39.958559400">  
 <warn>
     error starting service
     <iso-exception>
       Port value not set
       org.jpos.core.ConfigurationException: Port value not set     at org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer.initServer(QServer.java:92)  at
 org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer.startService(QServer.java:155)     at
 org.jpos.q2.QBeanSupport.start(QBeanSupport.java:118)  at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
 Method)    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
 sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)     at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
 Method)    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at
 java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
 java.base/sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:262)  at
 java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
    at
 java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
    at
 java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
    at
 java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
    at
 java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
    at
 java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
    at
 java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at org.jpos.q2.QFactory.startQBean(QFactory.java:187)   at
 org.jpos.q2.Q2.start(Q2.java:576)  at
 org.jpos.q2.Q2.deploy(Q2.java:360)     at org.jpos.q2.Q2.run(Q2.java:220)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
     </iso-exception>   </warn> </log> <log realm="Q2.system" at="2022-10-06T11:53:42.751307300" lifespan="286ms">
```

How to fix this?

Below is my code to start q2 server and deploy xml configuration file..

```java
@SpringBootApplication public class JposApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JposApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) 
    {
        Q2 q2 =new Q2();
        q2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your server configuration in the question, but the exception message suggests the `<port>` element is not present in the server configuration.

Comment: <server class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer" logger="Q2" name="xml-server-8000" realm="xml-server-8000">
<attr name="port" type="java.lang.Integer">8000</attr>
<channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.XMLChannel" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.XMLPackager" type="server" logger="Q2" realm="xml-server-8000">
<property name="timeout" value="180000"/>
</channel>
<request-listener class="org.jpos.iso.IncomingListener" logger="Q2" realm="incoming-request-listener">
<property name="queue" value="TXNMGR"/>
<property name="ctx.DESTINATION" value="jPOS-AUTORESPONDER"/>
</request-listener>
</server>

Comment: <port> is already present in the server configuration file as shown above.

Comment: xmlns="urn:jboss:service:7.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:jboss:service:7.0 http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-service_7_0.xsd"
Added this on xml configuration later due to  javax.management.ReflectionException: The MBean class could not be loaded and after that port value not set exception started to happen

Answer (score 0):

Your QServer is probably missing the attribute to set the port in which it must listen, you need to add something like this in the `QServer` deploy file:

```xml
<qserver ...>
    <attr name="port" type="java.lang.Integer">5555</attr>
    ....
</qserver>
```

Comment: <server class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QServer" logger="Q2" name="xml-server-8000" realm="xml-server-8000">
<attr name="port" type="java.lang.Integer">8000</attr>
<channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.XMLChannel" packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.XMLPackager" type="server" logger="Q2" realm="xml-server-8000">
<property name="timeout" value="180000"/>
</channel>
<request-listener class="org.jpos.iso.IncomingListener" logger="Q2" realm="incoming-request-listener">
<property name="queue" value="TXNMGR"/>
<property name="ctx.DESTINATION" value="jPOS-AUTORESPONDER"/>
</request-listener>
</server>

Comment: It is already added <Port> but still the issue persists. Giving Configuration exception.(Port value not set) . @Andrés Alcarraz

Comment: Are you sure you modified the deployed version of the file? Can you show, in your question please, not as a comment, the file structure and the file you modified there?

Answer (score 0):

It might be saying to specify the port number.

You can always specify or change the port numbers of application as below

- Go to your_project->application.properties

Add below line in that file.

```
# port number can be like 8081, 9090, 9091. replace XXXX with it.
server.port=XXXX
```